# ZipException in Logger

Tags: java

I'm running a crawler on twitter, it catches some exception twitter throws

```
Logger.getLogger(TwitterCrawl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
```

but occasionally, once or twice a week I get this exception

it's hard to debug because it does not occur very frequently.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:752)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:168)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:192)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader.loadClass(ResourceBundle.java:445)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2383)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1406)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1365)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1292)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1234)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:715)
    at java.util.logging.Level.getLocalizedName(Level.java:223)
    at java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format(SimpleFormatter.java:64)
    at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:179)
    at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:88)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:458)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:480)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:569)
    at com.twittercrawl.TwitterUpdate.getResults(TwitterUpdate.java:153)
    at com.twittercrawl.TwitterUpdate.updateTweets(TwitterUpdate.java:83)
    at com.twittercrawl.TwitterUpdate.runUpdate(TwitterUpdate.java:64)
    at com.twittercrawl.TwitterCrawl.main(TwitterCrawl.java:73)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:133)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:70)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URLClassPath.java:643)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$600(URLClassPath.java:538)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:605)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:597)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:750)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: It looks like you've got an invalid jar file in your classpath.

Comment: i'm using maven for dependency management, all files come from the central maven repository.

Comment: So then obviously you have no problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution so far? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @canavar no, I couldn't really reproduce the error, as it didn't really happen after I posted this.